# What is the proof of the formula for generalized permutations (permutations with finite repetition allowed)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have currently been studying discrete mathematics and combinatorics where I came across the introduction to generalized permutations in the textbook (Introductory Discrete Mathematics by V.K. Balakrishnan if that helps) in the chapter on combinatorics. I understand the derivation of the initial formula, of which is *P(n; n1, n2, ... nk) = (n!)/((n1)!(n2)!...(nk)!)* where *n* is the number of elements in set *X* and *n (subscript) i* (i = 1, 2, 3, ... ,k) is the number of elements of *X* in group *i*. The book then quickly gives another formula of which is equivalent of the form *P(n, r)/((n1)!(n2)!...(nk)!)* and furthermore derives from this the following three statements:

1) *P(n; n1, n2, ..., n(k-1)) = P(n; n1, n2, ... , n(k-1), m)* where *m = (n-(n1+n2+...+n(k-1))*

2)*P(n; r) = P(n; n-r) = P(n; r, n-r)*

3) (r!)P(n; r) = P(n, r)

What these three statements inherently mean and the derivation of them is something I would greatly appreciated.